# How can I prevent a desktop monitor screen from going to sleep when inactive on CentOs 7 Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, x11, display, suspend

How can I stop my monitor screen from going to sleep on CentOS 7 Desktop (X Windows) due to inactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step 1:

Go to **Settings**

[image: settings dialog]

#### Step 2:

Under **Power Saving** change **Blank screen** to *Never*

[image: power saving options]